# The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized

Tags: ado.net

I want to save the modifications I made to a DataSet into the DataBase, but I got this error:

> The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized

This is the code I wrote:

```
dr = dt.NewRow

dr(0) = t1.Text
dr(1) = t2.Text
dr(2) = t3.Text
dr(3) = d1.Value

dt.Rows.Add(dr)

da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand()
da.Update(ds, "stagiaire")
MsgBox("ajout effectu!")
```

> dr is a DataRow / dt is a DataTable / da is a SqlDataAdapter / cb is a SqlCommandBuilder / ds is a DataSet

But when I changed this line : `da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand()` with : `cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)` it worked.

So why the first code I used it didn't worked !

Answer (score 0):

Either you do it like this

```
 dr = dt.NewRow

 dr(0) = t1.Text
 dr(1) = t2.Text
 dr(2) = t3.Text
 dr(3) = d1.Value

 dt.Rows.Add(dr)
 SqlComand cmd=new SqlCommand("insert query",conn)
 da.InsertCommand = cmd
 da.Update(ds, "stagiaire")
 MsgBox("ajout effectu!")
```

OR

```
 dr = dt.NewRow

 dr(0) = t1.Text
 dr(1) = t2.Text
 dr(2) = t3.Text
 dr(3) = d1.Value

 dt.Rows.Add(dr)
 SqlCommandBuilder cb=new SqlCommandBuilder (da)
 da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand()
 da.Update(ds, "stagiaire")
 MsgBox("ajout effectu!")
```

Comment: Sometimes I just use `da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand()` and it works without using the `SqlCommandBuilder cb=new SqlCommandBuilder (da)` but in this case it doesn't work, and I want to know why